# Pi doesn't connect to wifi on boot?

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm using VNC viewer to connect to my Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Stretch. I set up my wifi connection using the wifi setting on the menu bar. However, after I reboot the Pi it does not connect to wifi automatically and I have to manually connect it. Extensive google research yielded no working solutions. I have tried editing the interfaces file and wpa_supplicant.conf but nothing has worked so far.

my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
        ssid="mywifiname"
        psk="mywifipassword"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Comment: I can only assume that in the field psk you actually didn't write the wifi password itself but the encrypted version of it as provided by wpa_passphrase, right?

Comment: er no I've written my wifi password as is. Unencrypted.

Comment: and it actually connects to the wifi at any given time? I don't think that's going to hold water, to the best of my knowledge

Comment: Apparently it's possible to use ascii text for the password so I think it's ok. Nevermind. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Comment: What's your system clock time?
[check it with `date` in the terminal]

Comment: hmm it was Thu 26 Apr 04:31:31 UTC 2018
which is wrong for my city. i updated it. but how does that affect the wifi?

Comment: i set the correct time and rebooted but it still doesn't auto connect to wifi

Comment: dont mix interfaces and dhcpcd (raspbian usually messes with dhcpcd for you through the gui so avoid interfaces if possible).  Much conflict and botched settings are possible.  If you have a spare sd, load a fresh graphical raspbian, set up the wifi to auto connect and then look at the resulting configs (maybe post them)

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks correct (assuming SSID and Password are correct) and you haven't modified any other files.

How are you accessing `VNC` if networking is not set?

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: I'm using an ethernet cable to connect the pi to my router

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a line `auto wlan0` in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. That should make it work.

Comment: You should at least explain why the OP should ignore the second line **Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd** in `/etc/network/interfaces` and what he **must** do with `dhcpcd`. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes.